# Why does this laptop have random wireless problems with DNS resolving?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, dns

The laptop seems to work 1/3 of times for www.google.ca, some websites seem inaccessible (i.e. don't work at all).  Firefox and Chrome seem to work (1/3 of time issue), and others computers here work perfectly - but that laptop is the computer of a friend.

I barely know his security, his hardware and stuff like that but I can find anything easily.  I have never seen a problem like that before, mostly because I make my computer my own (modding and tweaking them from scratch).

If you have some ideas of things to try, *please* tell me 'cause I'm stuck on this one and cannot reinstall his Windows because he doesn't have his recovery CD, and he has a very large amount of files to backup.

Another issue related to this one is that his laptop seem to show 2 wireless connections (we use wifi here, wep cause some hardware can't take more *wpa+*) like wireless1 and wireless2 (wireless replace the real network name)... It surely a dead simple problem but I'm maybe too avanced and I don't see noob errors sometimes cause I overlook some peoples skills ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your DNS servers with a third party DNS like OpenDNS and see if that helps:

```
Start -> Run -> ncpa.cpl -> right-click active wireless adapter -> Properties
Select Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) -> Properties
Select Use the following DNS server addresses
Preferred DNS server: 208.67.222.222
```

And disable or delete the extraneous wireless network to help narrow down the issue.